# Constant Visual Studio Update Required popup for Monogame 3.4 and Windows 10 UAP project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, win-universal-app, monogame

So, I’ve been trying to launch `Monogame` template on Windows Phone emulator with Visual Studio, but I couldn’t get it work.

This is what I have tried:

In my project I have encountered a problem with creating a Monogame project for Windows UAP in Visual Studio. I have tried to create a project with a Wizard tool, but after project creation I got the message that I need to install Universal Platform Tools

[see picture number 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPlPe.png)

after I pressed Install button an error has occurred

see picture number 2

,but the Visual Studio Setup window popped anyway. I have installed all the features that have been selected, but this didn’t help.

see picture number 3

Notification in Solution Explorer:
This project requires a Visual Studio update to load. Right-click on the project and choose “Download Update”.

see picture number 4

After clicking on “Download Update” it takes me to [this website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt188198.aspx)

After choosing “reload project” it displays the following error:

see picture number 5

after choosing highlighted option “Install” it takes me again to the mentioned website.

Does anyone know what I am missing or what should I do in this situation?

---

Installed Software:

Windows 10 Pro with latest updates

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1

Monogame 3.4 for Visual Studio

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your device navigate to

> \Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Extension SDKs\WindowsMobile\

From here you will find the version number of windows installed on your system.
Now Right click and click on 
**Edit YourProject.csproj**
Now here look for

```
<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.10240.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.10240.0" />
```

You will need to update this to the **version numbers** here to ones that is installed on your system esp the **minversion** number.
Now save it and you should be able to open up your project in most of the cases.
If that still doesnt fix the issue or if your project has been created for different version of windows app 8.1 etc then have a look at this [Microsoft Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt148501.aspx).
Hope that helps. But if in monogame you are still facing an issue try this [Webcached link](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://www.rizamarhaban.com/2015/08/29/monogame-uap-uwp-for-windows-10-build-10240/)